# Why does this 2-table SQL query work (partially) only with "UNION"?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables that I'm wanting to pull data from in the same query.  Here's the query that works (partially):

```
    $query = "SELECT city,radio,radio_site,rfacebook,rtwitter
    FROM brasil_radio
    UNION SELECT city,newspaper,newspaper_site,facebook,twitter
    FROM brasil_newspapers 
    WHERE state='Alagoas' 
    ORDER BY city 
    LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";
```

This query doesn't result in a blank page and does display data, but it doesn't put it all in the proper place.  (i.e. It lists the radio and newspaper sites all in the same column even though in PHP I've set up separate columns for each).

However, this seemingly more streamlined query results in a blank page:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM brasil_newspapers, brasil_radio 
    WHERE state='Alagoas' 
    ORDER BY city 
    LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";
```

A note about both tables referenced above...they each have seven fields, each have an autonumbered primary key.  One of the tables has a LOT less data than the other because I wanted to make sure this works, but I have all the records in each for the state "Alagoas" and again, the first example above partially works.  I'm really trying to figure this out and will be happy to furnish any other information you need.  BTW, I'm not trying to be lazy in the second query by using "SELECT*"...I've tried selecting only the columns I wanted and it still didn't work.

Thank you in advance and God bless.

Comment: Why do you think `UNION` and `JOIN` should work in similar way?

Comment: What is the question? If you're asking about SQL don't mix it with PHP saying `the query doesn't result in a blank page`

Answer (score 0):

A union combines the columns of your queries in the order they appear in the individual select statements. Since newspaper and radio are both in the same place, the union combines them into one column. Not sure if it helps your case, but you could at least separate them by doing something like:

```
 SELECT NULL as newspaper, radio FROM brasil_radio
UNION
 SELECT newspaper, NULL as radio FROM brasil_newspaper
```

Then the rows for the newspaper would have an empty radio column and vice versa.

The second query depends on your table layout. What you are doing there is a cross join, that means every row in every table is joined against every row of the other table. You probably don't want that. :) Are you seeing an SQL error on the second query? Because if both tables have a 'state' column, the product of your cross join will have two state columns, hence state = x is ambiguous and should throw an error.

Without knowing how exactly you'd like to display this data, I cannot tell you which type of query would work for you.